# NoClassDefFoundError when running local tests with only tenant-scp-neo included in POM

Tags: s4sdk

Motivated by this [blog entry](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/20/deep-dive-6-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-extend-your-cloud-foundry-application-with-tenant-aware-persistency/), I tried to implement multitenancy for our existing application on the classic SAP Neo SCP.

I added the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>tenant-scp-neo</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

to my POM and accessed the tenant in a test program via

```
String tenantId = TenantAccessor.getCurrentTenant().getTenantId();
```

Then, I got this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Multiset
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.monitoring.ExceptionMonitor.<init>(ExceptionMonitor.java:30) ~[core-1.9.5.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.monitoring.ExceptionMonitor.<clinit>(ExceptionMonitor.java:28) ~[core-1.9.5.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.logging.CloudLoggerFactory$CloudLogger.<init>(CloudLoggerFactory.java:67) ~[core-1.9.5.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.logging.CloudLoggerFactory$CloudLogger.<init>(CloudLoggerFactory.java:47) ~[core-1.9.5.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.logging.CloudLoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudLoggerFactory.java:19) ~[core-1.9.5.jar:na]
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.tenant.ScpNeoTenantFacade.<clinit>(ScpNeoTenantFacade.java:21) ~[tenant-scp-neo-1.9.5.jar:na]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems that the issue was a corrupt guava jar file in the Maven repository (within the `.m2` folder). Deleting the respective folders and having Maven download them again fixed the issue.

Comment: Hello [gigi.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9606786/gigi-com), if this answer solved your problem, please mark the answer as "accepted". Thanks.